# Azure Data Factory Passing a pipeline-processed file as a mail attachment with logic app

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipeline moving a file to a blob storage. I am trying to pass the processed file as a parameter of my web activity so that I can use it as an email attachment. I am successfully passing the following parameters:

```
{
 "Title":"Error File Received From MOE",
 "Message": "This is a test message.",
 "DataFactoryName":"@{pipeline().DataFactory}",
 "PipelineName":"@{pipeline().Pipeline}",
 "PipelineRunId":"@{pipeline().RunId}",
 "Time":"@{utcnow()}",
 "File":???????????????????????????? 
}
```

But, how should I specify the path to the file I just processed within the same pipeline?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Eric

Comment: I'm confused - are you trying to pass the file contents (bad idea) or the URL (good idea)? Assuming you want the URL, you may have to construct it from the information you used to create it. You should already have the sink account, container, file name, etc.

Comment: I want to pass the URL. Getting lost with the syntax.

Comment: The standard Azure Storage Blob URL format is https://{account}.blob.core.windows.net/{Path}/{FileName}

Comment: Hi @EricDBA, Only move one file at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I'm copying data to `output` container. My current assumption is to upload a file a day, and then use two GetMetadata activities to get the lastModified attribute of the file to filter out the name of the most recently uploaded file.

1. Get Child items in Get Metadata1 activity.
   [image]
2. Then in Foreach activity, get child items via dynamic content `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`
   [image]
3. Inside Foreach activity, in Get Metadata2 activity, specify the `json4` dataset to the `output` container.
   [image]
   Enter dynamic content `@item().name` to foreach the filename list.
   [image]
4. In If condition activity, using `@equals(dayOfMonth(activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified),dayOfMonth(utcnow()))` to determine whether the date the file was uploaded is today.
   [image]
5. In true activity, add dynamic content `@concat('https://{account}.blob.core.windows.net/{Path}/',item().name)` to assign the value to the variable.
   [image]
6. The output is as follows:
   [image]

Comment: Dear Harris Xu, My case is a different but your demo has been very helpful, so, many thanks! I filnally figured it out: I defined the web activity params as following:

{
 "Title":"Test Title",
 "Message": "Please review file content.",
 "DataFactoryName":"@{pipeline().DataFactory}",
 "PipelineName":"@{pipeline().Pipeline}",
 "PipelineRunId":"@{pipeline().RunId}",
 "Time":"@{utcnow()}",
 "AttachmentContainer":"/MyContainerName/",
 "AttachmentName":"@{item().name}"
}

and then used a function in the logic app to concat the "AttachmentContainer" with the "AttachmentName".